# selecting an item from listview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, listview, listbox

I am trying to show the selected item in listview in a message box, so using the following code

```
    private void lstMovie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { MessageBox.Show(lstMovie.FocusedItem.Text);}
```

it works fine for the first time but second time I try to select another item it throws an exception.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: are you using asp.net webforms project ?

Comment: no, I was using windows forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void lstMovie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(lstMovie.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
  MessageBox.Show(lstMovie.SelectedItems[0]); //Will select first selected item.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should rather be using [ListView.SelectedItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)  instead of [ListView.FocusedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.focuseditem.aspx)

> ListView.FocusedItem Property
>
> Although an item may be the one displaying the focus reticle, it may
>   not actually be a selected item in the ListView. Use the SelectedItems
>   or SelectedIndices properties to obtain the selected items in the
>   ListView control, the FocusedItem property is not necessarily
>   selected.